# When ionic run ios, raised error normal arm64, armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an android/ios application using ionic 1.

## A list of the version.

```
cordova: 7.0.1
ionic: 2.2.2
ios-deploy: 1.9.2
ios-sim: 6.1.2
node: v8.3.0
```

## A list of the plugins I used.

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation 0.0.1 "cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation"
cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.5.0 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0 "PushPlugin"
{}
```

## Issue

ionic ios run is operating normally, but suddenly it causes the following error.
I removed the platform several times and added it again. It still raises the same error.
One note I often reinstalled several times because of a conflict between the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin and the phonegap-plugin-push plugin. What's the problem?

```
Ld /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩 normal arm64
    cd /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/pbh/.rbenv/shims:/Users/pbh/.rbenv/shims:/Users/pbh/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.0.0/shims:/usr/local/var/pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/pbh/.scripts:/Users/pbh/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/pbh/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/pbh/.rvm/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -L/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/device -L/Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf -L/Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/device -F/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks -F럭스랩/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4 -filelist /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/럭스랩.app/럭스랩 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -ObjC -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a -lz -framework Bolts -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreMotion -framework AVFoundation -framework Photos -framework AddressBook -framework EventKit -framework Contacts -framework UserNotifications -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/armv7/럭스랩 normal armv7
    Ld /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩 normal arm64
(2 failures)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,럭스랩.xcworkspace,-scheme,럭스랩,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,럭스랩.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a common problem.

The solution to this problem is documented in phonegap-plugin-push documentation.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#bitcode